# Phaser 3 - Check group collision with world bounds

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my scenario, i create a ship according to player's preferences. The ship consists of the flag and the hull.

An example view

[image]

**PROBLEM-1**

Ship is an **Arcade.Group** and i want to prevent this group from going outside the borders of the world.

```
create(){
  // Create a group for ship
  this.shipGroup = this.physics.add.group()

  // Add hull to shipGroup
  this.shipGroup.create(400, 500, "1021")

  // Add flag to shipGroup
  const mainFlag = this.shipGroup.create(400, 500, "FA1")
  mainFlag.setOrigin(0.5, 0.8)

  // Set collision property to true of every object in shipGroup
  this.shipGroup.children.each((item: any) =>
    item.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
  )
}

update(t: number, dt: number){
    if (this.cursor.up.isDown) {
      this.shipGroup.setVelocity(...)
    }
    else {
      this.shipGroup.setVelocity(0, 0)
    }
}
```

With this approach every object in group calculated seperately. **After hitting the world boundary, the position of the objects is distorted**.

[image]

**PROBLEM-2**

To avoid this i tried another approach. I add bounding box to group. Instead of check collision for every object, i will only check collision for bounding box.

[image]

```
create(){
  // Create a group for ship
  this.shipGroup = this.physics.add.group()

  // Add bounding box for shipGroup
  this.shipBox = this.shipGroup.create(400, 500, "bbox")
  this.shipBox.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
  this.shipBox.body.onWorldBounds = true

  // Add hull to shipGroup
  this.shipGroup.create(400, 500, "1021")

  // Add flag to shipGroup
  const mainFlag = this.shipGroup.create(400, 500, "FA1")
  mainFlag.setOrigin(0.5, 0.8)

  /*this.shipGroup.children.each((item: any) =>
    item.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
  )*/
}
update(t: number, dt: number){
    if (this.cursor.up.isDown && !this.shipBox.body.checkWorldBounds()) {
      this.shipGroup.setVelocity(...)
    }
    else {
      this.shipGroup.setVelocity(0, 0)
    }
}
```

The problem is [checkWorldBounds()](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body#checkWorldBounds) returns false even if shipBox hits world boundaries. But collision for shipBox is work.

> checkWorldBounds()
>
> **Description**: Checks for collisions between this Body and the world
> boundary and separates them.
>
> **Returns:** True if this Body is colliding with the world boundary.

[image]

How can i implement collision for group and world boundary?

**P.S. :** phaser version is 3.55.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve/work around this issue, I personally would just use only one image why one physics-body *(hull and flag combined)* and just move that single image/texture, and switch the image, *when needed.*

That said, if you need to use the separate images, the easy way is to use a phaser `container`. *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html))*

1. create a container
2. add the images to the container
3. set the size for the container *(default size is width=0 height=0)*
4. create a physics body for the container
5. done

**A short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 0 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Ship with physics')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 40);
    graphics.generateTexture('ship', 10, 40);
    
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 10);
    
    graphics.generateTexture('flag', 30, 10);
    
    graphics.generateTexture('flag2', 20, 6);
    
    let hull = this.add.image(0, 0, 'ship')
    let flag = this.add.image(0, -5, 'flag')
    let flag2 = this.add.image(0, 10, 'flag2')
    
    this.ship = this.add.container(100, 80, [ hull, flag, flag2]);
    
    this.ship.setAngle(-90)
    
    this.ship.setSize(40, 30)

    this.physics.world.enable(this.ship);

    this.ship.body.setVelocity(100, 0).setBounce(1, 1).setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Info:** this demo is based partly from [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/container/arcade-physics-body-test)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I actually simplified the ship for the example. There are actually more combinations and I chose this method instead of creating images for each combination. But Phaser's documentation seems complicated, I'm lost in it.

Comment: @BK52 Glad I could help. I can understand the official docs, are not always very clear. That's why I often check out https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/, it's like a cheatsheet to the documentation. It doesn't cover 100% but the most common  things one would need. _(And I check the official examples  https://phaser.io/examples, since they are very extensive, but sometimes you have to dig around abit)_